# Merging multiple columns on pandas dataframe ("Vlookup" on different columns)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called `reference` and it looks like this:

```
    wind    P
0   15.5   300
1   16.0   333
2   16.5   421
3   17.0   498
4   17.5   544
```

and another one, called `vdb1` with all its columns with `wind` values. What I want to do is for each element in `vdb1`, replace it for the corresponding `P` on `reference` dataframe. I'm able to do it for individual columns, but as I have +10 columns to replace, I'm not getting there with only `pd.merge`.

Here is `vdb1`:

```
                   VDB1-01  VDB1-02 VDB1-03 VDB1-04 VDB1-05 VDB1-06 VDB1-07 VDB1-08 VDB1-09 VDB1-10 VDB1-11 VDB1-12 VDB1-13

2021-01-30 00:00:00 16.0    16.0    15.5    15.0    14.5    15.0    15.0    15.0    15.5    11.5    12.0    12.0    13.0
2021-01-30 00:10:00 15.5    15.5    15.5    15.5    15.0    15.0    14.5    15.5    15.5    11.0    11.5    11.5    13.0
2021-01-30 00:20:00 15.5    15.5    15.0    15.0    15.0    15.0    14.5    15.0    15.5    11.0    11.0    12.5    13.0
```

I'm trying to create another dataframe with the corresponding values, but I'm having some troubles with this:

```
expected1 = (vdb1.merge(reference,left_on=[vdb1.columns], right_on=['wind'],how='left'))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets map accross the values using map. values not in the rep(small datframe will become null). Lets fill those using combine_first.

```
vdb1.apply(lambda x: x.map(dict(zip(rep['wind'],rep['P'])))).combine_first(vdb1)
```